# How to access different model properties in same view in mvc4?Is it possible?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, models

Hi Is it possible to access the different model properties for same view

**My VisitorsViewModel model**

```
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
```

**My View_VisitorsForm Model**

```
    public System.Guid VisitingID { get; set; }
    public string Employee { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> VisitingDate { get; set; }
    public string StartTime { get; set; }
    public string EndTime { get; set; }
    public string SpendTime { get; set; }
    public string POVisit { get; set; }
```

I want to create 5 fields in  view **FromDate**,**Todate**,**CustomerName**,**Povisit** ,**StartTime**,**EndTime** **Employee**.  But all  these fields properties in different models. Is it possible to access two different model properties in same view? i tried to explain my issue as per my level best. please any one give me solution.

Advance thanks..

Comment: A View should only have one ViewModel.

Comment: mwilczynski  i want to keep fromdate and todate as textboxes  and remaining fields are need to display the data which is fetch from Db same as like which is mention in the below image   [Eg Op][3]
  [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YqhGm.jpg so i have to access properties from different models.

Comment: Then create new `ViewModel`, that combines properties of different models coming from DB. What's the problem? `ViewModel` is just a helper here to represent data for the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by mwilczynski, a view has one viewmodel only. The idea being the model contains exactly the data the view needs to render the page. Ideally, nothing more and nothing less.

From your image, it looks as if you need a viewmodel with a collection of data items to render the grid (visiting date ... Next appointment).
This is possible:

```
public class VisitorsViewModel
{
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }

    public ICollection<VisitViewModel> Visits { get; set; }
}
```

Where `VisitViewModel` is the viewmodel that contains the data retrieved from the database to show in the grid:

```
public class VisitViewModel
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string PoVisit { get; set; }
    public string StartTime { get; set; }
    public string EndTime { get; set; }
    public string Employee { get; set; }
}
```

The controller would look something like:

```
public ActionResult displaycustomer()
{
    // Get data from database
    List<View_VisitorsForm> objvisitlist = (from v in db.View_VisitorsForm select v).ToList(); 

    // Create a new viewmodel and fill it with the data you want displayed
    VisitorsViewModel viewmodel = new VisitorsViewModel
    {
        FromDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7), //(some default value)
        ToDate = DateTime.Now,               //(some default value)
        Visits = new List<VisitViewModel>()
    };

    foreach (View_VisitorsForm visit in objvisitlist)
    {
        viewmodel.Visits.Add(new VisitViewModel
        {
            CustomerName = visit.CustomerName,
            PoVisit = visit.POVisit,
            StartTime = visit.StartTime,
            EndTime  = visit.EndTime,
            Employee = visit.Employee
        }
    }

    // return a ViewResult with the viewmodel 
    return View(viewmodel);
}
```

In the view, you can access the properties in the `ICollection<VisitViewModel>` like so (I assume you want the visit date in a table):

```
<table>
@foreach (var visit in Model.Visits)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayValueFor(m => visit.CustomerName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayValueFor(m => visit.PoVisit)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: Arnoud  this is my controller code public ActionResult displaycustomer(){ List<View_VisitorsForm> objvisitlist = (from v in db.View_VisitorsForm select v).ToList();     return View();}  and i call the one model in another model as per you mentioned in your answer and i did all the things as per you said but i  getting error. i  want to load the list of data when the page get open so i wrote that list code(List<view_visitorsForm>  in controller now i got doubt which object i have to call in view objvisitlist (controller object) or Visits(model object). please clarify this doubt

Comment: I see data being retrieved in the controller, but not being used/returned to the view. I would expect a new viewmodel being created and the data from the linq result copied to the property Visits of this new viewmodel. After the model is created, it should be passed to the view as a parameter of the View method:   return View(viewmodel);  Oh, and I wouldn't put entities in viewmodels. From your comment I understand View_VisitorsForm is not a viewmodel as I thought before, but a (database) entity. I'll try to update my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You should just create a new ViewModel, like:

```
public class CombinedVisitorsFormViewModel
{
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
    public string Employee { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string StartTime { get; set; }
    public string EndTime { get; set; }
    public string POVisit { get; set; } 
}
```

And wire (or map, or however you want to call it) every property in your `Controller`, the same way you do with current ViewModels. ViewModel is a data representation for your particular view/views, so it can combine data from other models or even data not directly related with your DB `Model` at all.